# How can I manipulate the UI for this jQuery div scroller?

Tags: scrolltop, vertical-scrolling, custom-scrolling

I'm currently using the following code to scroll up/down text... I'd like to make the following modifications to the code, but am struggling on how to achieve it:

- Check the location of the text and affect the opacity of the
  up/down arrows. When the content of #scroll is at the top, the up (#scroll-up) arrow would be faded back. When the content of #scroll is at the bottom, the down (#scroll-down) arrow be faded back. Every where in between, both button's would be faded in.
- Hide the scroll buttons if they are not needed

Here's the current code:

```
var ele   = $('#scroll');
var speed = 25, scroll = 5, scrolling;
$('#scroll-up').mouseenter(function() {
    scrolling = window.setInterval(function() {
        ele.scrollTop( ele.scrollTop() - scroll );
    }, speed);
});
$('#scroll-down').mouseenter(function() {
    scrolling = window.setInterval(function() {
        ele.scrollTop( ele.scrollTop() + scroll );
    }, speed);
});
$('#scroll-up, #scroll-down').bind({
    click: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        if (scrolling) {
            window.clearInterval(scrolling);
            scrolling = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Updated code with up button functionality completed: http://jsfiddle.net/MzDst/8/

Comment: Still struggling with the other 2 items: 1) how to toggle the down button when the text reaches the bottom (note the div resizes) 2) how to hide when not needed.

Comment: Found the solution for the down button. Code updated: http://jsfiddle.net/MzDst/9/

Comment: I think I found the solve: http://jsfiddle.net/MzDst/11/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this might do the trick.

```
$(function() {
    var ele   = $('#scroll');
    var speed = 25, scroll = 5, scrolling;
    $("#scroll-up").css('opacity', 0.5);

    $('#scroll-up').mouseenter(function() {
        // Scroll the element up
        scrolling = window.setInterval(function() {
            ele.scrollTop( ele.scrollTop() - scroll );
            $("#scroll-up").css("opacity", (ele.scrollTop() == 0) ? 0.5 : 1);
            $("#scroll-down").css("opacity", (ele[0].scrollHeight - ele.scrollTop() == ele.outerHeight()) ? 0.5 : 1);
        }, speed);
    });

    $('#scroll-down').mouseenter(function() {
        // Scroll the element down
        scrolling = window.setInterval(function() {
            ele.scrollTop( ele.scrollTop() + scroll );
            $("#scroll-up").css("opacity", (ele.scrollTop() == 0) ? 0.5 : 1);
            $("#scroll-down").css("opacity", (ele[0].scrollHeight - ele.scrollTop() == ele.outerHeight()) ? 0.5 : 1);
        }, speed);
    });

    $('#scroll-up, #scroll-down').bind({
        click: function(e) {
            // Prevent the default click action
            e.preventDefault();
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            if (scrolling) {
                window.clearInterval(scrolling);
                scrolling = false;
            }
        }
    });
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    $("#scroll").css("height", winHeight - 220);

    if (ele[0].scrollHeight == ele.outerHeight()){
        $("#contentscrollnav").hide();
    }
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    $("#scroll").css("height", winHeight - 220);

    var ele = $('#scroll');
    if (ele[0].scrollHeight <= ele.outerHeight()){
        $("#contentscrollnav").hide();
    } else if (ele[0].scrollHeight > ele.outerHeight()) {
        $("#contentscrollnav").show();
    }
});
```

You can see the code in action at:
http://jsfiddle.net/MzDst/11/